# Can we call method using a variable if variable is none?

Tags: python

The following code, which I am trying to run and the value of var_pg is showing 0. The question is that why is it showing 0 whereas the fitness function is returning some value which is greater than 0?

```
def main():
  pop = {0,1,2,4,3,5}
  var_pg = find_best(pop)
  print('value of var_pg',var_pg)

def find_best(pop):
  var_pg = None
  for p in pop:
      if (not var_pg) or (var_pg.fitness()>p.fitness()):
          var_pg=p
      return var_pg

class CP:
  def fitness(self):
      c = 0.1*(5/41)
      self.__fitness = c
      return self.__fitness

main()
```

Can somebody please tell me what's am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The first return statement should be indented one times less, you want to return after the loop, not after the first iteration.

Comment: Value of fitness is const, so > condition is never satisfied. Also you are calling fitness member method on an int, instead of an instance of you CP class.  (var_pg is being set to int values)

Comment: You can replace `find_best` with the built-in `max` function, after choose a suitable `key` function to generate the comparison values.

Comment: and you never use `CP` class. first condition `not var_pg` is True, it never evaluates the second one (which will raise error)

Comment: Please read [ask] and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Your code does not work in the way you describe it. I assume you intended for `pop` to contain instances of the `CP` class, rather than integers. I also don't understand the question. It seems that you are trying to use the `fitness` method of your objects to decide which object is "best", but then you `print` *that object*? And then you're *surprised* that this doesn't show you the object's `.fitness` result, but instead the object itself?

Comment: I also can't understand how the title of your question relates to what you are asking. What does "call a method using a variable" mean? Do you mean that the variable holds the *instance*, or an *argument*? If it's the instance, then the only methods you can call on `None` are the ones supported by *its* class, `NoneType`. Using `.fitness` on it will not work. But your code *would not try* to do that, even after fixing the `pop` contents. (Hint: what do you think `not var_pg` will do, when `var_pg` is None? What do you think it will do, when it's an instance of your class?)

Answer (score 1):

At the first iteration of `for p in pop`, p is assigned to 0. `not var_pg` is thus True, so var_pg is assigned to 0 and returned, terminating the loop.

- `return var_pg` should likely go outside the `for` loop
- The arguments passed in `pop` are just integers, not `CP` objects, so they have no `fitness()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Because `return var_pg` is inside the loop and unconditional, the find_best() function will always return the first elements it gets from pop.  since pop is a set it could be any of the values. It just happens to be zero in this case.